# mysql adding index results to error

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, duplicates

I am using PhpMyAdmin to add indexes on the tables but whenever i try to add one it prints errors...

I have a table called `updates_categories` and i have a column named `created_date`... so i tried to add an index there and i get the following error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '2012-02-27 22:15:16' for key 'date_index'
```

i suppose that many entries have entered the same date(this can happen) but what does that mean?That i cant have an index on columns with same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add an index for only one field becouse most of the time it has no performance benefit on select but they got disadvantages on inserts. What is your table structure and what kind of queries are you using against it?

Comment: the structure is basic like (id, uid, name, created_date) and i will probably get the total categories of a user or print them in a list ordered by created_date DESC or ASC etc... i do the same with other tables as well...

Comment: PRIMARY: id
INDEX1: uid, id, name
INDEX2: id, created_date
If you have queries which are filtering data for example by the created_date you should create an index: created_date, id [, name]

Comment: but how can i create an index on 3 columns where one is text?(name)

Comment: For a text typed column you have the set it'S indexe's length (maximum is 255 byte if i'm remember correctly) but then you have no linmit to create an index from 3 columns. Are you sure you need text type for that column?

Comment: so its better for low characters length columns to change them to varchar instead of text?

Comment: Yes and the bests are the fixed length fields but their aren't always good choices. It's very important to choose the correct type for every column.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can - but don't use it as "UNIQUE" keys, just "simple" index.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of index did you try to create?

unique and primary key require that no key exists more than once

Comment: i really dont know the difference...i am still new to indexes... gotta read i think

Comment: unique index says what it does with it's name... it requires unique content wihtin the column it is assigned to.